# How to set the servers property of openapi with Apache Camel?

Tags: spring, apache-camel, openapi

I am trying to setup a openapi specification and publish the API with Apache Camel and Spring. I tried using restConfiguration, adding the property in the application.yaml, and using the @OpenApiProperty on the app. Everytime the generated yaml reads:

```
- servers
  - url: ""
```

```
platform:
  # not used
  urlrewrite:
    enabled: false
    token: ${LOCAL_TOKEN:}
    apim:
      token_ep: ${x/token}
      client:
        username: ${apim_client_username:}
        password: ${apim_client_password:}
        consumerKey: ${apim_client_id:}
        consumerSecret: ${apim_client_secret:}

  endpointsOrchestrated:
    server: myServer
    emr-endpoint: xxxxxxxx
  triggerName: ${PLATFORM_MODULE_ID}
  env: dev
  domain: ${PLATFORM_MODULE_DOMAIN}

openapi:
  title: My Sample api
  version: 1.0.0

camel:
  dataformat:
    jackson:
      auto-discover-object-mapper: true
  springboot:
    tracing: false
  rest:
    host: myhost.com
    port: 8080

spring:
  application:
    name: aaa
  profiles:
    active: ${ENV:local}

server:
  servlet:
    context-path: /
  port: ${TOMCAT_PORT:8080}
  host: localhost
  # MAX HTTP THREADS
  tomcat:
    threads:
      max: ${MAIN_HTTP_THREADS:200}
```